# Scheme - speed up a heavily recursive function

Tags: performance, recursion, optimization, scheme, racket

I must write a Scheme predicate that computes the function f(N -> N) defined as :

- if n < 4 :f(n)= (n^2) + 5
- if n ≥ 4 :f(n) = [f(n−1) + f(n−2)] * f(n−4)

I wrote a simple predicate that works :

```
(define functionfNaive
  (lambda (n)
    (if (< n 4) (+ (* n n) 5)
        (* (+ (functionfNaive (- n 1)) (functionfNaive (- n 2))) 
           (functionfNaive (- n 4))))))
```

Now, I try a method with an accumulator but it doesn't work...
My code :

```
(define functionf
  (lambda(n)
    (functionfAux n 5 9 14)))

(define functionfAux
 (lambda (n n1 n2 n4)
   (cond
     [(< n 4) (+ (* n n) 5)]
     [(= n 4) (* n1 (+ n2 n4))]
      [else (functionfAux (- n 1) n2 n4 (* n1 (+ n2 n4)))])))
```

Comment: What's the point of using an accumulator here? Optimisation of run time? Wouldn't you rather go for memoization (works very well with your procedure)?

Comment: @uselpa can you demonstrate how to memoize? I haven't used memoization in racket yet.

Comment: @naomik A simple way to implement memoisation is to create a hash table, with the argument(s) as the key, and the result(s) as the value. The fun part is to write a function adapter to do all that behind the scenes so that you can memoise a function as simply as `(define func (memoise (lambda ...)))`. :-D

Comment: @uselpa It is for better performances. Here I can't compute f if n is too large.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young writing a `memoise` adapter sounds fun. Maybe an idea for your next blog post ?

Comment: @naomik That is indeed my plan. :-)

Answer (score 4):

As requested, here's a memoized version of your code that performs better than the naïve version:

```
(define functionf
  (let ((cache (make-hash)))
    (lambda (n)
      (hash-ref!
       cache
       n
       (thunk
        (if (< n 4)
            (+ (* n n) 5)
            (* (+ (functionf (- n 1)) (functionf (- n 2))) (functionf (- n 4)))))))))
```

BTW... computing the result for large values of `n` is very quick, but printing takes a lot of time. To measure the time, use something like

```
(time (functionf 50) 'done)
```

AND here's a generic memoize procedure, should you need it:

```
(define (memoize fn)
  (let ((cache (make-hash)))
    (λ arg (hash-ref! cache arg (thunk (apply fn arg))))))
```

which in your case could be used like

```
(define functionf
  (memoize
   (lambda (n)
     (if (< n 4) 
         (+ (* n n) 5)
         (* (+ (functionf (- n 1)) (functionf (- n 2))) (functionf (- n 4)))))))
```

Comment: I was tinkering with a generic memoization procedure and holy smokes, yours is so much simpler and elegant than i was coming up with. Very cool answer.

Comment: Would it be possible to take a badly written procedure, such as `(define (badfib x) (if (< x 2) x (+ (badfib (- x 1)) (badfib (- x 2)))))`, and then memoize that? `(define goodfib (memoize badfib))`. My hunch is that it's not possible because `badfib` internally refences itself, which is not the memoized version, `goodfib`. Even if it's not practical, I think it would be cool to see if you could memoize an existing function using a generic `memoize` adapter.

Comment: @naomik Yes. I assume `badfib` is in global scope so it's possible to do `(let ((oldfib badfib)) (set! badfib (memoize oldfib)))`. It will be O(n) first time around and O(1) second.

Comment: @Sylwester is there a way which leaves the original `badfib` in tact ?

Comment: @naomik If you are defining the procedure in your code you could make a macro that makes two versions where the recursive call is wraped in a lexical variable to locally change where the recursion goes to. [Here is an example](https://gist.github.com/westerp/ff6ced1d625f219ca759)

Answer (score 1):

First, that's not a predicate. A Predicate is a function which returns a Boolean value.

To calculate the *n*th result, start with the first four and count up, maintaining the last four known elements. Stop when *n* is reached:

```
(define (step a b c d n)
  (list b c d (* (+ c d) a)) (+ n 1)))
```

etc. Simple. The first call will be `(step 5 6 9 14 3)`.

Answer (score 1):

The depth of the recursion tree may be the biggest question, so may be use the iteration which means use some variables to memory the intermediate processes.

```
#lang racket
(define (functionf n)
        (define (iter now n1 n2 n3 n4 back)
          (if (= n now)
              back
              (iter (+ now 1) back n1 n2 n3 (* n3 (+ back n1)))))
        (if (< n 4)
            (+ 5 (* n n))
            (iter 4 14 9 6 5 125)))

(functionf 5)
```

in this way, the depth of the stack only be 1 and the code is speeded up.